# Function is returning type error on code wars, don' know why

Tags: javascript

I'm on CodeWars right now, here is the link
https://www.codewars.com/kata/camelcase-method/train/javascript
The goal is to take in a string `like this` and return it in camel case `LikeThis`. I have written a solution that works in other javascript environments (codeStich) but when I try to run it on CodeWars the first two tests pass and then it returns a fail. Here is my code:

```
String.prototype.camelCase=function(){
  string = this.split('');
  string[0] = string[0].toUpperCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i ++) {
    if (string[i] === ' ') {
      string[i + 1] = string[i + 1].toUpperCase();
      string.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return string.join('');
}
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`
I really cannot understand why this is happening as the code works on other websites
edit:
Here are the two tests that pass `'test case'.camelCase(); 'camel case'.camelCase();` when it reaches this test, it fails `'camel case method'.camelCase();`. My main confusion is to why this doesn't work on CodeWars, it works fine in other environments

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca — No, it is looping over every character, not every word.

Comment: You should provide an [mcve] (preferable as a live demo embedded in the question). Showing some input data which causes the problem would help.

Comment: `string[i + 1]` will be undefined when i = string.length - 1 ... `works in other javascript environments` not true javascript if your code works

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that wouldve been better but this should still work. Will try your solution

Comment: It has nothing to do with environment, your tests just don't pass. Try your implementation on this string: `like this     `. (pay notice to trailing spaces)

Comment: also, your use of global variable `string` is disconcerting

Comment: @ritaj I just tested it with `like this` and it worked just fine

Comment: "Pay notice to trailing spaces"

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm pretty sure this is true javascript, this is the website I use for school, but please give it a look. https://codestitch.io/743e49f6
Also whether or not `string[i + 1]` is `undefined` is irrelevant if I trim the padded spaces right off the bat. Will do so and test

Comment: @ritaj good point. How would I go about trimming this? I tried `this.trim()` and `this = this.trim()` and nothing worked

Comment: `string = this.trim().split('');`

Comment: @Marcus - the code in your question throws at that site, you said it passed - perhaps the code in the question is not the code you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some basic checks to verify if character at that position exists.

```
String.prototype.camelCase=function(){
  //your code here

  string = this.split('');
  if(string[0])
  string[0] = string[0].toUpperCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (string[i] === ' ') {
      if(string[i+1])
      string[i + 1] = string[i + 1].toUpperCase();
      string.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return string.join('');
}
```

I tried submitting this piece of code and it passed all the tests.

Comment: You don't need this at all, just trim the string.

Comment: `return this.trim()[0].toUpperCase()+this.trim().slice(1).replace(/\s+(.)/gi,(_,c)=>c.toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like this

1.

```
function camelCase(a){
string = a.trim().split(' ');
var temp = []
if(string[0])
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
temp.push(string[i].replace(string[i].charAt(0), string[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()))
}
return temp.join('');
}
```

2.

```
function camelCase(a){
string = a.trim().split(' ');
var temp = []
string.map(function(item,index){
temp.push(item.replace(item.charAt(0), item.charAt(0).toUpperCase()))
})
return temp.join('');
}
```